# Eclipse java autocomplete stopped working after adding library

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons

I've found similar problems while searching, but not a fix for this specifically.

Disclaimer, I am fairly inexperienced, sorry if this is super basic. Thank you so much for any help in advance.

I've downloaded the apache commons language pack 3
                    commons-lang3-3.8.1 specifically for the array tools.

I made a folder, called 'lib' for importing the libraries.

Right click - lib(folder) -> import, add libraries.

Right Click - ProjectFolder -> Properties -> Java Build Path(on the left) -> Libraries(Tab) -> Add JARs -> (add the apache stuff) -> Apply and Close

**Then autocomplete stops working in that specific project**
I frequently use stuff like typing **main** then ctrl + space fills out the main method, or typing sysout and doing ctrl + space. This behavior is repeatable if I make a new project and do the same thing. Why does this happen? It make it impossible to do something I desperately need to do.

Thank you so much for any time and help offered.

EDIT: When I try, it says no default proposals. Just to add detail.

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use (see _Help > About_)? In _Window > Preferences: Java_, does clicking the _Rebuild Index_ button fix this issue? Are there any errors in that project (see _Problems_ view)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to submit it incomplete. Let me retry that, as I can't edit it now.

Thank you so much for responding!

Rebuild index does not change anything. I think that button applies to the entire IDE, whereas my issue is local to projects that I add the apache libraries to.

I am using Java Photon Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.9.0. Do you think installing an older version could solve my issue?

This behavior is repeatable in simple error free "Hello world" programs, so this isn't anything to do with error in the code. Thank you so much for helping so far.

Comment: Please [upgrade to Eclipse 2018-09](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) and try again. Could you share your `.classpath` file?

Comment: 4.9.0 is the current  2018-2019 version of Eclipse Java. Thank you for all your help, but I think I just figured it out. Creating a new eclipse workspace and migrating all my projects over seems to have fixed my issue. 

Again, thank you so much, I wish I could repay you for your time.